# check server radio button control using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radio-button

I am having one .js file in which i written,

**sample.js**

```
function pageLoad(){
  $('.rbNewUnit').attr('checked', true);
}
```

**sample.aspx**

```
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rbNewUnit" runat="server" CssClass="rbNewUnit"  Text="New Unit" GroupName="categotyOfUnit" />
```

it is not working.

I tried also but does not working

```
 $('.rbNewUnit').is(':checked');
```

if i put first code in script tag in .aspx page its working. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pageLoad is reaserved keyword in Sys.Application of Microsoft Asp.net Ajax. That functiona is called for all postbacks including asynchronous postback. Functions in $(document).ready won't be called during  asynchronous postback. For more info go through documentation [here](http://asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/overview/AJAXClientEvents.aspx) and article that explains the difference between

[$(document).ready and pageLoad](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)

I've used your code and modified it a bit and it works for me even if I put pageLoad function in external js file.

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/demo.js"></script>

<ajax:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" >
</ajax:ScriptManager>
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbNewUnit" runat="server" CssClass="rbNewUnit"  Text="New Unit" GroupName="categotyOfUnit" />
```

Make sure you've referenced external JS file correct.

**JS:**

```
function pageLoad(){
   alert($('[id$=\'rbNewUnit\']').attr('id'));
    $('[id$=\'rbNewUnit\']').attr('checked', 'checked');
   alert($('[id$=\'rbNewUnit\']').attr('checked'));
}
```

It will find element with id that ends with **rbNewUnit**. I've kept alert as it is so that you can check out issue incase you may want to debug. Remove alert and alter code as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NJvuh/)**

You must write the function body inside your document ready:

```
$(function () {
    $('.rbNewUnit').prop('checked', true);
});
```

- It's better to use `prop` instead of `attr` in this case (if you are using jQuery 1.6+).

---

References:

- [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) - jQuery API Documentation

Comment: $(function (){}) is equivalent to $(document).ready() ok... but whatever inside this function it will stop working after any postback. so that's why i used pageLoad() event to ignore this issue. but still i am not able to check a radio button using prop() method.

Comment: Are you using `Update Panel`?

Comment: yes i am using update panel. but i don't think this is the issue of update panel.. because when i put my code $('.rbNewUnit').attr('checked', true); in script tag of .aspx page it works fine

Comment: It is because your update panel. Why you want to `checked` your radio button with javascript? and why not using `ASP.NET` itself?

Comment: i have drop down in which there is 4 value if i select 1st then div with id say "1stDiv" will show up. this div has a radio button which must be checked because on my click event i check that id this radion button is checked i need to store data whatever in "1stDiv"

Comment: Put your `<script>` tag inside your UpdatePanel.

Comment: but i don't want to use script tag. i want all my jQuery code in a separate .js file

Comment: You must recall your function whenever your update panel get fired with `ScriptManager`. [Check this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750.aspx).

Comment: your jsFiddle does not working if i put pageLoad() event insted of $(function(){}).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30613/discussion-between-nox-and-aijaz-chauhan)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#' + '<%=YourRadioButton.ClientID %>').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

**For jQuery 1.6 or higher use**

```
$('#' + '<%=YourRadioButton.ClientID %>').prop("checked", true)
```

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
function pageLoad(){
$('.rbNewUnit').attr('checked', true);
}
 window.onload = function(){pageLoad()}
```